# Galois representation attached to $3$-torsion points of an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let

$ E $ - Elliptic curve defined over $ {\mathbb{Q}} $.

$G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ - The absolute Galois group, $\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) $ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

$ E[3] $ - $3$-torsion points of $ E $.

Suppose $ \rho$ denotes the $ G_{\mathbb{Q}} $-representation associated to $ E[3]$. 
If $ E $ has a $3$-torsion point over $ \mathbb{Q} $, how to prove
 $$
    \rho   \sim
   \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & \eta \\
    0 & \chi \\
   \end{array} } \right)
 $$ where $ \chi $ is the mod 3 cyclotomic character $?$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that $E$ has a rational $3$-torsion point, that point must be fixed, and hence your representation takes the form
$$ \rho \sim \left( \begin{matrix}  1 & \eta_{i} \\ 0 & \chi \end{matrix}\right)$$
as you say. It's a general fact that the determinant of the $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ representation attached to an elliptic curve is the cyclotomic character. This follows because the Weil pairing is bilinear, alternating, and Galois-invariant. (See Proposition III.8.1 in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.)

Comment: If $E$ has no rational $3$-torsion point, will $\rho$ still have the same representation $?$

Comment: @Robert No, not necessarily.

Comment: @Robert No, never.